# Lightning: How to refresh other components

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have created & added 4 different components in Lightning page and I want to refresh all of them if any components records get change.

I know that, In order to refresh the specific component we can use 
 [`$A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();` event](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_force_refreshView.htm).

but how i can communicate refresh event from one components to another ?

Comment: Does force:refreshView not refresh the complete view? Are you saying the other 3 components are not updating when you trigger force:refreshview event?

Comment: There are indeed some components that do not handle `force:refreshView`. For example, if you have a custom component that creates a record in a community and also have a standard list view component on the same page, the list view will not listen to the event to update the records in the list after a new one is created. The only workaround we have found is to navigate away then back to force the framework to recreate the list view component.

Comment: Yes, force:refreshView is working for one components but not for the other component

Answer (score 4):

You can listen to exact that event in another component, just add a handler:

```
<aura:handler event="force:refreshView" action="{!c.onRefreshView}" />
```

As this is an application event all components declaring interest in handling this event will be notified, regardless who is dispatching the refresh view event

Comment: Does this mean that, there has to be one handler for every component to refresh every component inside an app?

Comment: Yes, every component must register a handler

Comment: thanks for reply. can you explain how the other components will listen this action="{!c.onRefreshView}" ? can you please provide the example ? thanks

Comment: please post another question, however, i would suggest you read the [lightning component developer guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/intro_framework.htm) and accept the answer if it helped you. thanks!

Comment: Thanks Chris - I got the answer here. https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2015/07/lightning-components-2.html Intercomponent communication